# "Support of" vs. "Support for"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"Show your **support for** the XYZ (Organization name) this season" or "Show your **support of** XYZ (Organization name) this year"?

I have seen *support of* and *support for* both being used.  Is there a rule?

"Show your **support of** our clients" or "show your **support for** our clients"? (*Support* to be used in the context of making a donation)

Comment: I'd say "your support for" but "in support of" (American English).

Answer (score 15):

*Support of* an organization means that it is the organization that is giving the support. *Support for* an organization means that the organization is receiving support.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used expression with *of* is *in support of* and according to NOAD means:

> giving assistance to: *air operations in support of the land forces.* • showing approval of: *the paper printed many letters in support of the government.* • attempting to promote or obtain: *a strike in support of an 8.5% pay raise.*

In your example I would use *for* not *of*, as the support is *for them* not *of them*.