# Support for/of/to a specific standard or norm

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, software

I already checked this answer: ["Support of" vs. "Support for"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91106/support-of-vs-support-for) but since the context is not the same, I am not sure of the right answer.

Here is the context: say that you are talking about a specific software which integrates a specific standard or norm. How should I express it ?:

- "The current version of the software comes with **a support for** the XYZ norm/standard"
- "The current version of the software comes with **a support of** the XYZ norm/standard"
- "The current version of the software comes with **a support to** the XYZ norm/standard"

Thanks,

Comment: No, HanniBaL90. None of those is acceptable, for the simple reason that you misused "… a support" where "… support" alone was not simply preferable but necessary.

That said, “support for”… and never “a support for”… would be correct and “support of” and “support to” don’t work.

Comment: So the right answer is support for ? Can you explain why I should not put an a before ?

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't research that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"support for" and "support of" are both in use, however I'd recommend:

*The current version of the software supports XYZ norm/standard*